# “dimension less than 8” or “less than 8 dimensions”?

Tags: word-usage

This question is midway among English and mathematics, meaning that it requires acquaintance with both, but since I am interested in the correct English way to say something, I ask it here.

Is it more correct – or usual – to say “a space of arbitrary dimension” or “a space of arbitrary dimensions”? (I am referring here to any kind of vector, Euclidean or other geometric space.)

Analogously, should I say “a space of dimension less than 8” or “a space with less than 8 dimensions”? Or are both correct?

EDIT: I am referring here to the mathematical notion of dimension: for a vector space, the maximal number of linearly independent vectors (and corresponding definitions for other kinds of space).

Comment: "Dimension" in common English means something else than it does in mathematics. If you are talking about the dimensions of a space, most people will think about (only!) three of them, length, width and height. You are most likely talking about n-dimensional spaces, or spaces with n dimensions. Hence, you want spaces with less than x dimensions.

Comment: *A space of dimension less than 8* sounds like saying that the space is of less than 8 units in some (or possibly in *each*) dimension. *A space with less than 8 dimensions* is talking about a space with 7 or 6 or 5 ... dimensions. Regarding *a space of arbitrary dimension(s)*, I'm not sure what your intended meaning is; they could each mean different things depending on context.

Comment: **Fewer** dimensions = less error

Comment: A space of [dimensionality](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dimensionality) less than 8; **or** less than 8 dimensions.

Comment: A space with fewer than 8 dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

A 7-dimensional vector space is said to have dimension less than 8. We do not say that it has less than 8 dimensions.

If you want to say that a result holds for 1-dimensional vector spaces, 2-dimensional vector spaces, and so on, write *This result holds for spaces of arbitrary/any dimension*.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is probably referring to the *dimension* (singular) of the space.

It is more usual to use the adjective *dimensional*. A mathematical context prefers *n-dimensional space* over either "space of arbitrary dimension" or "space of arbitrary dimensions."

> The dimension of Euclidean n-space E<sup>n</sup> is n. When trying to generalize to other types of spaces, one is faced with the question "what makes E<sup>n</sup> n-dimensional?"
>   [Wikipedia: Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension)

If the OP's situation forces a choice between dimension/dimensions, the above quote might nudge him toward using "a space of arbitrary dimension," although "n-space" or "n-dimensional space" are used more often by mathematicians.

Similarly, one might prefer "space of dimension less than 8" when referring to, say, Euclidean 3-space. I believe the OP is referring to the *dimension* of the space as opposed to how many *dimensions* the space has.

(Although this is a forum about English, I agree with the choice of "less than" over "fewer than" here, since it is a mathematical concept and the concept is always spoken and written as "less than.")

(Please also see this article on [Hilbert space dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Hilbert_dimension), which refers to the concept as *Hilbert dimension* (singular).)